# Using Sage to compute facts about modules

Tags: modules, programming, sagemath

I am new to programming in general but in my project, I am required to work with a finite set $S = \{A_1,...,A_n\}$ of $m \times n$ matrices over a finite ring $R$, and the submodule $M$ they generate. To be more specific, I would like to compute facts such as: Maximal lin. indep. set of columns for each matrix, maximal lin. indep. subset of $S$, minimal generating set of $M$, span of S, length of $M$ and a composition series if it exists, and free rank of largest free submodule of $M$ (or possibly the set of all submodules/free submodules of $M$, which is finite since $R$ and $S$ are finite). However, while browsing through the documentation in the Sage website, I found very little in terms of commands that compute the above facts for suitable $R$, could someone point out a source that refers to (some of) the above commands? I apologize in advance if the question violates forum rules or is more suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: There's also https://ask.sagemath.org. What kind of finite rings are you working with, and how do you define them? (e.g. by quotients of free rings?)

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I'm working with finite chain rings or finite principal ideal domains in general. Most of the time, the ring in question is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, a Galois ring $\operatorname{GR}(p,n,r)$ or a suitable quotient of the latter.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is even implemented in Sage for commutative rings. You can sure define the matrices, but I didn't manage to find an analogue of the 'column_module' or 'column_basis' method that would work with $\Bbb Z/(8)$. 'kernel()' throws "Echelon form not implemented over 'Ring of integers modulo 8'". However Sage is distributed with Singular (you can open it by typing 'singular_console()'), here is a [manual](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/index.php/singular.pdf). I didn't work with it directly but you may try, starting with section 3.1.1 where they define some kinds of rings.